# Fetching data from MongoDB with some conditional statements in the backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, frontend, backend

The following code fetches all of the data (here products) from the MongoDB and sends it to the frontend.
I want to change this by introducing some conditions (if else statements) and only those products which satisfy that condition, should be fetched from the database.

```js
const getProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const pageSize = 10
  const page = Number(req.query.pageNumber) || 1

  const keyword = req.query.keyword
    ? {
        name: {
          $regex: req.query.keyword,
          $options: 'i',
        },
      }
    : {}

  const count = await Product.countDocuments({ ...keyword })
  const products = await Product.find({ ...keyword })
    .limit(pageSize)
    .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))

  res.json({ products, page, pages: Math.ceil(count / pageSize) })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of MongoDB operators that you can use to find the data based on your conditions. Here are some operators that you can try: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/